# OpenStack+OpenContrail: Do I need to ensure OpenStack network state is clean before integrate OpenContrail with an existing Openstack?

Tags: cloud, openstack, virtualization, sdn

I'm trying to integrate OpenContrail as SDN Controller with an existing OpenStack installation.

Before this choice i also read the OpenDaylight project documentation for the ODL Installation on an existing OpenStack. I learnt that, before the installation, I should ensure OpenStack network state is clean.

OpenContrail documentation doesn't refer to this kind of requirements.

The question is: Do I need to ensure OpenStack network state is clean before integrate OpenContrail with an existing Openstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that:

"After its integration, Contrail will ignore all information in the neutron db. Any incoming neutron api call will be translated to a contrail-api call.

Contrail itself does not use the Mysql database but has its own (Cassandra) databases

So any router/subnet/network/interface etc object that currently exists in the neutron/mysql database is ignored.

That basically means you will need to re-create each object that you are using with neutron".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to clean `Openstack` before integrating with `Contrail`.
Though the already created networks on Openstack will not be available in contrail dashboard. All the future networks which you create in Contrail will be synced with Openstack.